# Show Price with and without taxes into Product Page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem into a Prestashop 1.7 solution.

Into a Product page, i want to show 2 prices (include and exclude VAT)

```
<span itemprop="price" content="{$product.price_amount}">{$product.price}</span>
```

This example show price with VAT. I don't find how show price without VAT too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{debug}` in your `.tpl` and you will see all available variables that you can use.

Our you can use `{$product|@var_dump}` which will show you what sub-variables the `$product` variable contains

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, this variable {debug} save me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{$product.price_tax_exc}` variable to display price with tax excluded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i help but need more variable to create a same result than {$product.price} (XX.XX €)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `displayPrice()` method that you can use to format the price displayed.

But since version `1.7.6` you should use the `formatPrice()` method, since `displayPrice` is deprecated.

You can use it like this:

```
{block name='product_without_taxes'}
    {if $priceDisplay != 1}
        <p class="product-without-taxes">{l s='%price% tax excl.' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%price%' => Context::getContext()->currentLocale->formatPrice($product.price_tax_exc, $currency.iso_code)]}</p>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

This way you'll have the price formatted with the current currency and the `tax excl.` text. For example in French it will display `10,00 € HT`, 'HT' meaning 'tax excluded'